# tailwind responsive design displaying block regardless

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm currently in the moment learning tailwind. I'm trying to make these three divs inline when full screen but in smaller screen block. Right now, it is block regardless.

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'flex flex-col bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-lg shadow-xl']) }}>
    <div class="text-center items-center px-6 py-3 bg-gray-900 rounded-lg rounded-b-none space-x-12 ">
          <div class="sm:inline-flex block items-center">                
             <span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->likes_count }}</span>
             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-white">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" 5" />
             </svg> 
          </div>
    
          <div class="sm:inline-flex block items-center">
             <span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->comments_count }}</span>
             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-white">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" "/>
             </svg>   
          </div>
    
          <div class="sm:inline-flex block items-center">
             <span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->reads }}</span>
             <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <path d=""></path>       
             </svg>        
          </div>   
       </div>
      </div>
```

If I've understood the documentation right, you use unprefixed utilites to target mobile. Which is block currently and then prefixed larger screen which is sm:inline-flex at the moment, but right now, it displays block either way, what I'm doing worng exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by using flex direction on the parent element for these screen sizes:

```html
<div class="text-center items-center justify-center px-6 py-3 bg-gray-900 rounded-lg rounded-b-none space-x-12 flex flex-col md:flex-row">
    <div class="w-100 flex">
       <span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->likes_count }}</span>
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-white">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2 5" />
       </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="w-100 flex">
       <span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->comments_count }}</span>
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-white">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"/>
       </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="w-100 flex">
       <span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->reads }}</span>
       <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <path d=""></path>
       </svg>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Let me know if this works.